# VB.net progress bar while installing a printer

Tags: vb.net

i have a listbox with a bunch of printers and by selecting a printer and pressing the install button, the printer gets installed. the process takes 30-45 seconds where the application freezing but it is installing at the background. is there anyway to place a progress bar that shows something is happening instead of the freezing. this is the part of the code where the printer is installing. doesnt need a progress bar but any type of activity to show something is happening while the driver is installing

```
 Dim objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

 MsgBox("Printer Driver is Installing, Please wait",, "Installing")

 objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\printserver\" + CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem)
 objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem)
 objNetwork = Nothing
```

thanx in advance

Comment: The line after `MsgBox()` won't run until the user dismisses the message... which might be a while, given the message asks them to wait.

Comment: And rather than a progress bar, have you considered showing a looped animation.  Progress bars are great and all, but kind of require you know the steps and finite duration type info

Comment: Start with setting the cursor to Wait, and setting it back when done. Combined with a ToolStripStatusLabel.Text with your status message it might be enough.

Comment: @joel Coehoorn, I put the msgbox just for testing and to show what i want to do here for anyone who want to help coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really choose any way to tell the user to wait while doing background tasks. Here is an option with a ToolStripStatusLabel and Cursor update. It uses Async/Await to create the Task to not freeze your ui.

```vb
Option Strict On

Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary

' ---

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Printer Driver is Installing, Please wait"
        Dim name = CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Await addPrinterAsync(name)
    Finally
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Ready"
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function addPrinterAsync(name As String) As Task
    Return Task.Run(
        Sub()
            Dim objNetwork As New WshNetwork() '= CreateObject("WScript.Network")
            objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection($"\\printserver\{name}")
            objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(name)
        End Sub)
End Function
```

I have also added a COM reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model` which allows you to put `Option Strict On` and create the printer with strong types. But that is optional but you can always go without as you have.

I just don't think a MsgBox will work because the user can close it any time they like even if you manage to get it to show non-modal and not freeze the ui.

Comment: that what i was looking for. that was brilliant. thanx alot